Can't find transaction by signature (Helius Webhook + RPC, Node.js server)
i am building a token mint tracker using Helius Webhooks to listen for on-chain events. Each time the event triggers i send the information to a function that extracts the signature and then tries to find the transaction via getParsedTransaction(). The problem is as follows: the signature comes through and is logged as expected however it just can't fetch the transaction. Whenever i paste the signature in solscan it finds and/or whenever i hard-code a signature that was received 5-10 seconds ago it works. Setting a 5-10 second timeout didn't work so something else must be wrong. Here is a code example below:
INDEX.JS FILE
app.post("/webhook", async(req,res) => {
  await getTokenInfo(req.body);
  res.status(200).send('Webhook received');
})

getTokenInfo function
async function getTokenInfo(info) {
  for (const x of info) {
    const signature = x.signature;
    await tokenWork(signature);
  }
}

async function tokenWork(signature) {
  try {
    console.log('Fetching transaction for signature:', signature);
    const transaction = await connection.getParsedTransaction(signature, { maxSupportedTransactionVersion: 0 });

    if (!transaction) {
      console.log('Transaction not found for signature:', signature);
      return;
    }

    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.error('Error fetching token info:', err);
  }
}

It was 1 function before and it still wasn't working so i split it into 2 but it still didn't work and left it like that. Connection to helius is established outside the function, keeping it inside the function didn't change anything too.
Please help :(

Take a look at the guidelines and explanations about the transaction confirmation times (and in case how consensus works on Solana):

https://solana.com/docs/advanced/confirmation
https://www.helius.dev/blog/how-to-land-transactions-on-solana

Briefly, Solana has three tiers of transaction confirmation statuses - commitment levels:

processed: the most recent transactions that were built by a validator recently but have not been confirmed by the consensus (~400 ms)
confirmed: it's to be confirmed by 2/3 of the validators, I believe it's about 1-3 seconds
finalized: more than 31+ blocks were built on top of the one where the particular transaction has landed (~15 s)

Then with all of this, it takes some time for RPC to load the newest data and for indexers to index them and start to display (i.e., time delay when the Solana Explorer can show the transaction existence).
As well, a discrepancy amongst different RPC nodes happens. E.g., when you check for data at Helius RPC endpoint your request is load-balanced to one RPC machine. That one, the first machine, has some knowledge of the state of the chain. For another request, you can be load-balanced to another RPC machine that may have a different perspective on the state.
a) the most "hacky" way could be to set the timeout to +15 seconds
If the RPC provider you use for webhooks is the same as the one you query for getTransaction then I believe the trouble would be most probably in setting the commitment level you want to read.
I cannot find the commitment level of transaction signatures that Helius webhook works with (https://github.com/helius-labs/helius-sdk#webhooks) but I think it could be processed as it's usually used.
You need to specify the same level of the commitment for the getTransaction as well. When you do not specify anything then the default level should be taken from the solana configuration file, which should be ~/.config/solana/cli/config.yml, see getTransaction code https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-web3.js/blob/v1.92.2/packages/library-legacy/src/connection.ts#L4955
b) you can manually specify the commitment level on the call to processed (still it may probably happen on very rare occasions that if the transaction was processed but at the end it's not finalized (after 15s) then if you query the signature after the timeout time you will not get it as it will be considered the transaction never happened)
getParsedTransaction(signature, {
  maxSupportedTransactionVersion: 0,
  commitment: 'processed',
})

c) find out how to configure Helius webhook endpoint to provide only Finalized transactions (while maybe still using processed commitment when getParsedTransaction)
